# Custom Control usage in XML-View. Error after deployment: Can't find object class

Tags: sapui5

i've devloped an ui5 application and created a new custom control in it. I saved the new control js-file to the "control" path of my webapp (in my example the File MyInput.js for the control 'MyControl'). 
Running my app in WebIDE for testing runs without any problems. But after deploying the app to an abap system, i now get the error message from the XMLTemplateManager, that it can't find the object class.

Here a shorted version of my View using my Control:

```
<mvc:View xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc" xmlns="sap.uxap" xmlns:layout="sap.ui.layout" xmlns:m="sap.m" xmlns:forms="sap.ui.layout.form"
    xmlns:core="sap.ui.core" xmlns:ssuc="sap.suite.ui.commons" xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:table="sap.ui.table" xmlns:cmns="sap.ui.commons"
    xmlns:dvp="de.fiori4cls.Fi4ClsFV.control"
    controllerName="de.fiori4cls.Fi4ClsFV.controller.FVView" displayBlock="true">
    <m:Shell id="shell">
        <m:App id="app"> 
            <m:pages>
                <m:Page id="fvViewPage" title="{i18n>SachPruef}">
                    <m:content>
                        <dvp:MyInput                                            
                            value="{ path : 'Cls>/Currency', type : 'sap.ui.model.type.String' }"
                                     vhTitle="{i18n>Currency}"/>
                    </m:content>
                </m:Page>
            </m:pages>
        </m:App>
    </m:Shell>
</mvc:View>
```

Here 'de.fiori4cls.Fi4ClsFV' is the Id of my app (as declared in manifest.json under part 'sap.app' in attribute 'id'.

Any idea why this runs in WebIDE Test and why this throws the mentioned errors when deployed to abap system?

kind regards
Matthias

Comment: What is the UI5 version in the ABAP system? Is the app deployed as a stand-alone app? Or is it launched from FLP? If stand-alone, could you share your bootstrap settings from index.html?

Comment: Hi. UI5-Version on Abap: 1.44, an older version of ui5 which needs to be supported by the app. UI5-Version in WebIDE was higher. If i set version in WebIDE to 1.44 i have the same problems with the app when testing in WebIDE. Bootstrap in WebIDE-Test is as follows, but on abap-system it runs in launchpad.
`
 <script id="sap-ui-bootstrap"
   src="/resources/sap-ui-core.js"
   data-sap-ui-theme="sap_belize"
   data-sap-ui-resourceroots='{"de.fiori4cls.Fi4ClsFV": "./"}'
   data-sap-ui-compatVersion="edge"
   data-sap-ui-async="true"
   data-sap-ui-frameOptions="trusted">
  </script>
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solved the problem myself with a mix of debugging, try and error :-)

For those you are running into a similar problem here the solution.
The problem was the definition of my control. So everything above the view (see my question above) is ok so far.

But my (simplified test-) control startet like this:

```
    return Input.extend("MyInput", {
            "metadata": {
                "properties": {
                    // Title of Value-Help Dialog
                    "vhTitle"   : { type : "string", defaultValue :"Title" }
                }
            },
            init : function() {
                // Call inherited Method 
                Input.prototype.init.call(this);
                this.setShowValueHelp(true);
                this.attachValueHelpRequest(this.onValueHelpRequest);
            },

            renderer: sap.m.InputRenderer,

            // ======= Events
            onValueHelpRequest : function(oEvent) {
                var me = this;
                console.log("MyInput->onValueHelpRequest->Entering");
                var lvTitle = this.getVhTitle();
                alert (lvTitle);
            }

    });
```

I found that this runs with UI5 version 1.54 and above. But not with a UI5 version blow 1.54. 
What solved the problem, was to fully support the control-class with its namespace. After that i ran into another additional problem, that my renderer-function is not defined. I only wanted to inherit the renderer of the extended control because it does not make any changes to the rendering itself. Here the key was to set the renderer-class in quotationmarks.

So here is my fully working test-control that now runs with ui5 1.44 and above.

```
    return Input.extend("de.fiori4cls.Fi4ClsFV.control.MyInput", {
            "metadata": {
                "properties": {
                    // Title of Value-Help Dialog
                    "vhTitle"   : { type : "string", defaultValue :"Title" }
                }
            },
            init : function() {
                // Call inherited Method 
                Input.prototype.init.call(this);
                this.setShowValueHelp(true);
                this.attachValueHelpRequest(this.onValueHelpRequest);
            },

            renderer: "sap.m.InputRenderer",

            // ======= Events
            onValueHelpRequest : function(oEvent) {
                var me = this;
                console.log("MyInput->onValueHelpRequest->Entering");
                var lvTitle = this.getVhTitle();
                alert (lvTitle);
            }

    });
```

Applying this to my "real" control makes it running :-)

kind regards
Matthias